# Change access to static web ressources on runtime spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, togglz, featuretoggle

I use Spring Boot and Spring Security in my project to manage the delivery of static web resources. Until now, it was sufficient for my application to identify users via Spring Security and allow them to access these resources. Subsequently, I control the delivery of certain resources via Feature Flags (https://www.togglz.org/documentation/spring-boot-starter.html). By using Feature Flags, it is possible to check if a Feature (e.g. "TEST") is enabled by calling a `FeatureManager` Bean during runtime like this: `manager.isActive(FeatureToggles.TEST)`. In order to access the flag for managing web resources, I tried to use the mapping functionality of Spring:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")    
public class IndexController {
    private FeatureManager manager;

    public IndexController(FeatureManager manager) {
        this.manager = manager;
    }

...

   @RequestMapping(path ="myFeature/")
    public ModelAndView redirectToMyFeature(ModelMap modelMap) {
        if (manager.isActive(FeatureToggles.TEST)) {
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:", modelMap);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Unfortunatelly, this code leads to an infinite loop. I wonder how to handle a mapping to the same path with conditions (see code above). Are there other ways to use Spring Boot in order to control the delivery of certain resources during runtime?

Comment: can you explain me why it is making an infinite loop with a scenario? you mean, even static resources are also being asking for authentication?

Comment: because what i made is that /myFeature/ redirects to /myFeature/ so the redirectToMyFeature method is called again and again. And there is a "302 Found" on browser console. 

All static resources are protected and ask for authentication and this is the desired behavior. But I sill don't want to make ressources under the path /myFeature/ accessible, even for authenticated users, until the flag "TEST" is enabled in the UI Administrator Console of FeatureTogglz.